# Ag-grid date filter datepicker not loading in edge (works in chrome)

Tags: javascript, datepicker, ag-grid

I have a date field using the filter: `agDateColumnFilter`

When I load the grid in chrome and select to filter this date field the dialog presented contains an input of type 'date' allowing me to open up a datepicker.

When I perform the exact same action in Microsoft Edge then an input of type 'text' is rendered in the dialog and I am unable to open up a datepicker. Despite Edge supporting inputs of type 'date'.

Does anyone know how to force it to render an input of type 'date' or if there is a way of defining a custom filter with some custom html that I can place a custom datepicker or something?

The version I am currently am using is:

```
"ag-grid-community": "20.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "20.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for defaultDateComponent in the github repo for ag grid, I can see the following logic to converting the input type to `date`

```
if (_.isBrowserChrome() || (params.filterParams && params.filterParams.browserDatePicker)) {
    if (_.isBrowserIE()) {
        console.warn('ag-grid: browserDatePicker is specified to true, but it is not supported in IE 11, reverting to plain text date picker');
    } else {
        this.eDateInput.type = 'date';
    }
}
```

The missing filter param to set is `browserDatePicker`. Setting that to `true` in the params now displays a datepicker in Edge:

```
{
    headerName: 'My date field',
    field: 'dateField',
    sortable: true,
    filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {
      browserDatePicker: true
    }
  }
```